# Conditional enrichment in Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas Dataframes, which consist of the same columns and are partly filled with similar data. Each row in the dataframe has a unique id.

```
df1
      ID        A            B      C      D 
0    23149       -112.2      15     454   456 
1    89799      -221.84      12     454   
2    11589       339.93      48           564
3    67867       -855.5      13         
4    7898         68.4       90         
5    789         45.1        10       
6    456          4564       12
```

```
df2 (before)
      ID        A            B      C     D 
0    23149       -112.2      15         
1    23154         68.4      90       
2    11589       339.93      48         
3    97897       -855.5      13         
4    89799      -221.84      12
```

I want to enrich the columns C and D in df2 with values from df1.

- ID, A and B should not be changed in df2
- If an ID exists in both dataframes the values for C and D should be added from df1.

In my example I expect a dataframe similar to this.

```
df2 (afterwards)
      ID        A            B      C     D 
0    23149       -112.2      15    454   456  
1    23154         68.4      90          
2    11589       339.93      48          564
3    97897       -855.5      13    
4    89799      -221.84      12    454
```

How can I implement this conditional filling?

Comment: Use left join with `merge`

Comment: pd.concat([df1, df2.reindex(df1.index)], axis=1)